# How do I copy a file in multiple folders in Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, cp

I have directory named "**public**" in every directory inside **Documents**.
I want to copy file named **File.txt** in every directory "**public**".

```
cp -r File.txt Documents/*/public/
```

doesn't seam to work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm very certain that using **cp** combined with **xargs** would do just what you want to do if you know how to use 'em... or you can just write a script to perform just that

Comment: Follow above duplicate link and scroll down.